# Python2 - How to remove characters from output?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I made this script that outputs the balance of a group of addresses. The output however comes in a list of one. How do I get python to extract the value from the list, so it doesn't show the ['']?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/xpub/xpub6BfKpqjTwvH21wJGWEfxLppb8sU7C6FJge2kWb9315oP4ZVqCXG29cdUtkyu7YQhHyfA5nt63nzcNZHYmqXYHDxYo8mm1Xq1dAC7YtodwUR')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

balance = tree.xpath('//*[@id="final_balance"]/font/span/text()')

print str(balance)
```

Regards.

Comment: Probably `print balance[0]`.

Comment: Or better yet: `balance = tr.xpath(...)[0]` and then just `print balance`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
balance = tree.xpath('//*[@id="final_balance"]/font/span/text()')[0]

print balance
```

When you have a list `foo`, `foo[0]` gets the first element of `foo`. Since your list has only one element, that's the *only* element of `foo`. Then you can just print it out. (Similarly, you could use `foo[1]` to get the second element, `foo[2]` to get the third, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: balance
Out[1]: ['0.00622801 BTC']

In [2]: type(balance)
Out[2]: list

In [3]: ''.join(balance)
Out[3]: '0.00622801 BTC'
```